# Remove JavaScript code from react-native release build

Tags: react-native

I have various debug code for different environments in my react-native app. Some of that shouldn't end up in the release build, since it describes development environments or other things that should stay internal.

With native Android apps I can avoid this by generating code on build for different flavors or stripping code with ProGuard. Is there a similar way to do this with JavaScript code in react-native?

Answer (score -1):

If you use the `__DEV__` variable to determine the environment, babel should remove the dead code in production builds.

```
if (__DEV__) {
  // development code
}
```

Comment: Should, but won't :-/